# J2me Polish integration error with Eclipse as plugin

Tags: eclipse, java-me, j2mepolish

I am trying to integrate the J2ME polish into the Eclipse IDE as plugin.

I have followed all the instructions given into the J2ME polish site:

http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/installation/ide-integration/eclips/installation.html

But i cant see any J2ME polish updates into my eclipse. In Windows->preferences (There is not any other option for the J2ME polish available, as i can see so many other installed software)

Is anybody aware about this issue in the eclipse? If anybody has any other solution or any other option to install J2ME polish into the eclipse,which would be appreciated.

Comment: The above link to installation is improper this is the actual link

http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/installation/ide-integration/eclipse/installation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you point to the eclipse home correctly? all it takes to add a eclipse plugin is to drop the required jars in to eclipse plugins folder!

Answer (score 1):

Their eclipse integration seems broken at present. http://www.j2mepolish.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=850&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=